# Angular can't get data from the server

Tags: angular, http

I'm using the latest angular, imports and other angular things are normal. I have such code:

```
...class definition
ngOnInit(){
 this.http.get("http://localhost:5000/getData").subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
});
}
```

Where `localhost:5000/getData` returns data in json. And angular is on the `http://localhost:4200/` and it has its own routers. The data is correct, but I'm unable to use this.data outside the `subscribe()` method(no errors just `this.data` field is empty). Where am I wrong? What should I do to fix it?(I fixed troubles with same origin policy because other things work in normal way). I have to display data from the server into my component;

Comment: when you trying to use what error you are getting? and where you are using?

Comment: I don't have any errors my this.data is empty and that's all

Comment: is it empty all the time? where are you using the `this.data`

Comment: I initialized it in the class definition, in subscribe method `this.data` has value, but outside subscribe `this.data` has no value again. I use it in my component

Answer (score 1):

subscribe is asynchronous, you can't get the value while initialization of the component that way, the value is not available yet, if you have some action to do with data, you can call a function inside subscribe:

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:5000/getData").subscribe(data => {
   this.data = data;
   this.doAction(this.data);
});
```

you can use async Pipe to display data in the view:
change your code and use .map thus an Observable will be returned :

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
this.data= this.http.get("http://localhost:5000/getData")
              .map(response => response.json());
```

and in your view use async pipe, no need to subscribe

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (data | asyn)"> {{item}}</div>
```

Comment: I only have to display my data into component

Comment: Do I have to take `map()` from rxjs?

Comment: you don't need to import anything

Comment: by the default I don't have property `map()`

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Answer (score 0):

```
    private display = "downloading";    
    ngOnInit(){
     new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ 
      this.http.get("http://localhost:5000/getData").subscribe(data => {
       resolve(data);                  
      });    
     }).then(data=>{
      if(data['someKey']!==undefined){  
       this.display = "downloaded";    
       this.data = data;            
      }else{this.display = "noData";}   
     });
   }
```

It's my solution where I show different views while data are loading from the server. View depends on `display`